# Does aws glue accepts events directly from the eventbridge

Tags: aws-glue

can you pass the events directly from the AWS event bridge to AWS glue? Does AWS glue create a new cluster every time to process the event? What will be the processing time for the event?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly pass parameters from the EventBridge event to the AWS Glue job and need to use medium for that like S3.

However, it is possible to setup AWS Glue workflow that consumes events from EventBridge: here is instructions from Amazon how to do so: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/starting-workflow-eventbridge.html

AWS Glue is a serverless solution so it run on cluster provisioned already and you don't need to warry about it. You will be charged per DPU-Hour see for details: https://aws.amazon.com/glue/pricing/

Processing time is really depends on your job configuration like transformations etc.